# Android: clicking the foreground notification from a service doesn't show activity

Tags: android

**edit:** My code worked fine, I was simply giving it the wrong Activity class (multiple APK build project using shared library).

---

I'm using the following code to display a foreground notification for my [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). For some reason though, it doesn't show me my activity when I click on the notification.

I've checked out various StackOverflow posts and followed accordingly, and even the sample [FakePlayer](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Notifications/FakePlayer/src/com/commonsware/android/fakeplayerfg/PlayerService.java) from CommonsWare but to no avail.

```
protected void updateNotification(String subtitle) {
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Show notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_headset_mic)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle("AirWaves: " + G.SETTINGS.deviceName)
        .setContentText(subtitle)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true);

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Anyone have an idea where I might be going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

**i have also implement notification consider the following example**

```
public void sendNotification(Context context,String message, String action) {
            try {
                int icon = R.drawable.notilogoboss;
                String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", message);
                intent.putExtra("action", action);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logoboss))
                        .setSmallIcon(icon)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                int notId = UUID.randomUUID().hashCode();
                notificationManager.notify(notId, notificationBuilder.build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following method to create the pending intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class );
intent.putExtra( "message", message );
intent.putExtra("action", action);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( context );
stackBuilder.addParentStack( MainActivity.class );
stackBuilder.addNextIntent( intent );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

notificationBuilder.setContentIntent( pendingIntent );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the flag for the pending intent to this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also, what is the `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());` method that you are using? can you post that as well for additional help?

Comment: Service.startForeground() is part of the Android framework to run services in the foreground. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

Comment: Sorry. Confused it with a custom method.